# TypeError: texts_to_matrix() got an unexpected keyword argument 'num_words'

Tags: keras, stringtokenizer, txt

python code

[image]

the problem is when uploading a txt file and try to run the code as shown in the picture I'll get the error

TypeError: texts_to_matrix() got an unexpected keyword argument 'num_words'

Comment: Give the code block and error log in the question itself, not in an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You passing "num_words" argument at wrong place. Check below code snippet.

```
from tf.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=10)
tokenizer.texts_to_matrix(texts, mode="binary")
```

Checkout this official documentation https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/text/Tokenizer

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution if you are reading the model from your directory then follow the steps:

```
    import pickle
    with open('./outputs/tokenizer'+model_name+'.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
         tokenizer = pickle.load(handle)
 
    tokenizer.num_words = 10000
```

If you face the dimensions mismatch then you can verify what is the pre-define num_words. Just run -

```
print(tokenizer.num_words)
```